# Filtering a multi-dimensional Knockout observableArray with ko.utils.arrayFilter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, knockout.js

I have an observableArray that looks something like this:

```
this.menuItems = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "level1", subItems: [
        { name: "level1-1" },
        { name: "level1-2" }
    ] },
    { name: "level2" },
    { name: "level3", subItems: [
        { name: "level3-1" },
        { name: "level3-2", subItems: [
            { name: "level3-2-1" }
        ] },
    ] },
    { name: "level4" }
]);
```

This renders a multi-level navigation menu. So some items can have subItems, others don't. And the number of levels is unknown.

Now I have a 'filter navigation' input to filter these things.

```
var self = this,
    menuFilter = ko.observable(""),
    filter = menuFilter().toLowerCase();

    if (filter === "") {
        return self.menuItems();
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.menuItems(), function (item) {
            if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

This works great for top-level items, but I'm not sure the best way to loop through `self.menuItems().subItems`, and then then next level, and next, etc.

Any ideas?

**edit:** I just created this JS Fiddle and it seems to be working. Now I have to figure out how to get it going on my [slightly more complicated] app.

http://jsfiddle.net/KSrzL/7/

**edit (again):** My latest issue is that the top level has no information, so I have to START with `.children`, which isn't working.

http://jsfiddle.net/KSrzL/8/

Comment: Is the semicolon at the end of the `menuFilter` declaration line supposed to be a comma? You're making `filter` a global variable, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Good find. That was just a typo. And this is all within a namespace'd object. I didn't include certain things for simplicity-sake.

Comment: OK. What kind of output do you want from your filter function? Do you want to preserve the hierarchical structure, so that all ancestors of matching items are kept? Or do you just want a flat list of all of the matches, regardless of how they were nested in the original tree?

Comment: Ideally they'd keep the hierarchy, if possible.

Comment: I got this working (not really sure how, or what's different between this and the app I'm working on): http://jsfiddle.net/KSrzL/7/

Comment: I feel like I'm getting closer, but not really getting it. A major issue is that the first level has no data, so I'm trying to start at the `children` level. http://jsfiddle.net/KSrzL/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/MRtRm/

The key pieces:

```
self.nonNullItems = function(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(x) { return x !== null; });
};

self.filteredObjectOrNull = function(obj, query) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        var filteredChildren = self.nonNullItems(obj.children.filter( function(x) { return self.filteredObjectOrNull(x, query); }));
        if (filteredChildren.length > 0)
            return {name: obj.name, children: filteredChildren};
    }

    if (self.matchText(obj.name, query))
            return obj;

    return null;
};

self.filterItems = function() {
    var filter = self.itemFilter();

    if (filter === "") {
        return self.items();
    } else {
        return self.nonNullItems(self.items().map( function(x) { return self.filteredObjectOrNull(x, filter); }));
    }
}
```

I think it could be simplified in a couple of ways but it seems to pass the testing I did. (You should add a couple more levels of menu to make sure.)

Comment: Wow, man. That's intense. And it works perfectly. One issue I came across is that the top level of the array I get from the server is blank, so I have to start on `children`. But when I do that, filtering breaks. Any ideas regarding that? http://jsfiddle.net/MRtRm/4/

Comment: Remember that `self.items()` is an array that contains one object (and it’s this object that has the `children` property you want). If you do `self.items().children` you’re trying to get the `children` property of the array itself. You need to look at the first element of the array, so: `self.items()[0].children`. If I were you, though, I’d set it up so that `self.items()` gives you `self.items()[0].children` instead of the raw server response like it is now.

Comment: Oh, right! Didn't even realize that. Thanks a lot - helped so much!

Comment: Hey man (sorry I keep bothering you) - I'm getting errors with the filterArrayWithQuery function. Obj is not defined. I don't see how/where the function is ever called anyway and looks safe to remove completely (maybe?). Any thoughts/insight?

Comment: Yeah, the `any`, `filterItem`, and `filterArrayWithQuery` functions were things I was playing around with... you should delete them.